# How to generate anonymous access link to a file using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I need to create anonymous access link to files in my SharePoint online site by sending server relative URL as a parameter. 
http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.sg/2016/01/whats-new-in-sharepoint-2016-remote-api_28.html mentions about a newly added method called `createAnonymousLink` but I do not know how to invoke this.

I can fetch the anonymous access urls by invoking

```
 https://siteName/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items(1)/GetObjectSharingInformation?$expand=SharedWithUsersCollection&retrieveAnonymousLinks=true
```

I am consuming this REST API from a Java Application

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it as below using REST api:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

 var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.Web.CreateAnonymousLink";
          console.log(url);
          $.ajax(
          {
              'url': url,
              'method': 'POST',
              'data': JSON.stringify({
                 'url': _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/Shared Documents/test.txt',
                 'isEditLink': true
              }),
              'headers': {
              'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
              'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
              'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
              },
              'success': function (data) {
                    console.log(data.d.CreateAnonymousLink);
              },
              'error': function (err) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
               }
          }
          );
         }
```

If you are using CSOM C#, you can use it as below:

```
// Create anonymous link for document
string link = ctx.Web.CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument(
                 "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/docs/sample.doc",
                 ExternalSharingDocumentOption.View);
```

if you want it to expire after certain days, it is as below:

```
// Create anonymous link with expiration for document
string link = ctx.Web.CreateAnonymousLinkWithExpirationForDocument(
                 "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/docs/sample.doc",
                 ExternalSharingDocumentOption.Edit,
                 DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));
```

Reference links:

[External sharing API for SharePoint and OneDrive for Business](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2015/10/02/external-sharing-api-for-sharepoint-and-onedrive-for-business/)

[Rest Api Generate Guest Link SharePoint Online](https://reshmeeauckloo.wordpress.com/2016/09/12/create-anonymous-link-sharepoint-online-rest/)

[PnP.Core.ExternalSharing](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.ExternalSharing)

Comment: I need to use this API from a java application. I have edited my question to include this information

Comment: yes, so you can use the REST api call for invoking this method. 
replace, _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl with your sharepoint site url

Comment: you can invoke this in Java, like you invoke any other POST request. I am not very familiar with Java coming from c# background, but you can use it like this i believe - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily

Comment: @GautamSheth - Any idea why I cannot get the Rest API version working in Postman?  Looks like maybe I am doing something wrong with the body payload formatting...?

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254950/sharepoint-createanonymouslink-with-rest-api-in-postman

Comment: @GautamSheth, do you know how to generate a sharing link for external users with authentication (anonymous links are too much of a security hazard for us)