# SharePoint CreateAnonymousLink with Rest API in Postman

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

According to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2015/10/02/external-sharing-api-for-sharepoint-and-onedrive-for-business/), [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/How-to-get-guestaccess-URL-of-on-item-file/td-p/34962), and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/197009/how-to-generate-anonymous-access-link-to-a-file-using-rest-api) resource, one can call the Web.CreateAnonynousLink via the Rest API (in addition to CSOM).  I am trying to get a working example going in Postman, but not having any luck.

**Headers & Error:**
[image]

**Body:**
[image]

I can successfully access the search API in another Postman tab for the same tenant, using the same Bearer token.

A few people who are having similar issues:

- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Creating-anonymous-access-links-through-REST-API/m-p/145937
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325403/create-a-sharepoint-anonymous-link-using-rest-api

Comment: To create the link, i think you dont need the `If-Match` and `X-Http-Method` parameters in the headers. Also, can you try with `{'url': 'https://tenant/sites/pub2/Appointment Forms/Appointment form example.docx', 'isEditLink': true}` as payload, do replace with your actual values though :)  ?

Comment: @GautamSheth - Yea, I tried that as well with the same results.  Sorry, I should have updated the screenshot.  And I have tried with/without the additional headers. They were just some troubleshooting attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test steps with use user context to test the rest api in postman, you could refer [this thread](https://denuwanhimangahettiarachchi.blogspot.com/2017/03/generate-sharepoint-online-rest-api.html) to get user context.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing a screenshot example!  I guess my confusion is why you need to include the user context at all (X-RequestDigest).  According to Vesa's article, these Rest URL's should be available using the bearer token.  Unless I am misunderstanding his guidance.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2015/10/02/external-sharing-api-for-sharepoint-and-onedrive-for-business/ (Scroll down to the bottom and look at the first FAQ). I am building a B2B proxy web API, so I won't have any user context.